# GridSearchCV - Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am trying to do a **Neural Network Classification** using `scikit-learn` in python.

I generated my data, split it to train and test, and used it in the model `MLPClassifier()`.

What I plan to do next is to evaluate the parameters used in this model using `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs, make_moons
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=500, centers=5, n_features=2, random_state=10, cluster_std=2.5)
y[y==0] = -1
X_train, X_test,  y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=10)
```

`X_train` and `X_test` are arrays with 2 features.

```
model_MLP_RAW = MLPClassifier()
model_MLP_RAW.fit(X_train, y_train)
model_MLP_RAW.predict(X_test) == y_test
model_MLP_RAW.score(X_test, y_test)

model_MLP_RAW = MLPClassifier()

param_gridMLPC = {
    'learning_rate': ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"],
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [x for x in itertools.product((10,20,30,40,50,100),repeat=3)],
    'alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)],
    'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "tanh"]
}

CV_unknwnMLPC = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_MLP_RAW, param_grid=param_gridMLPC, cv= 5)
CV_unknwnMLPC.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(CV_unknwnMLPC.best_params_)
```

Everything works fine but at the line `CV_unknwnMLPC.fit(X_train, y_train)` I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-90faf7e56738> in <module>()
     10 
     11 CV_unknwnMLPC = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_MLP_RAW, param_grid=param_gridMLPC, cv= 5)
---> 12 CV_unknwnMLPC.fit(X_train, y_train)
     13 
     14 print(CV_unknwnMLPC.best_params_)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    638                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    639           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 640                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    641 
    642         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    456             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    457         else:
--> 458             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    459 
    460     except Exception as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in fit(self, X, y)
    971         """
    972         return self._fit(X, y, incremental=(self.warm_start and
--> 973                                             hasattr(self, "classes_")))
    974 
    975     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _fit(self, X, y, incremental)
    324 
    325         # Validate input parameters.
--> 326         self._validate_hyperparameters()
    327         if np.any(np.array(hidden_layer_sizes) <= 0):
    328             raise ValueError("hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s." %

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _validate_hyperparameters(self)
    390         if self.max_iter <= 0:
    391             raise ValueError("max_iter must be > 0, got %s." % self.max_iter)
--> 392         if self.alpha < 0.0:
    393             raise ValueError("alpha must be >= 0, got %s." % self.alpha)
    394         if (self.learning_rate in ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"] and

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I checked some answers online and I double-checked the parameters in `param_gridMLPC` to make sure they're well provided but the error persists.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)]

In the [documentation of MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier):-

> **alpha** : **float**, optional, default 0.0001
>
> L2 penalty (regularization term) parameter.

`"alpha"` should be float. So in the parameter grid, it can be a list of different floats.

But when you do this:

```
'alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)]
```

This becomes a list of numpy array. That is a sort of a sequence of sequence (list of list, array of array, 2-d array etc). That means that the first element of list is an numpy array which will be passed to the internal `MLPClassifier` in place of `"alpha"`. That is the error.

You can do the following:

```
'alpha': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)
```

That will be a simple array, from which the elements (float values) will be chosen to send into the model.